# Using 'OR' in CakePHP find

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.2 and following find().

```
if($filter_data_array['age_younger'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.age <= "] = $filter_data_array['age_younger'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['age_older'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.age >= "] = $filter_data_array['age_older'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['go_date_after'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.go_date >= "] = $filter_data_array['go_date_after'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['go_date_before'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.go_date <= "] = $filter_data_array['go_date_before'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['client'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.client_id = "] = $filter_data_array['client'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['case_name'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.name = "] = $filter_data_array['case_name'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['case_ref'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.case_reference_i_d = "] = $filter_data_array['case_ref'];
        }

        if($filter_data_array['instruction_date'] != '')
        {
            $conditions["icases.date_instruction_received >= "] = $filter_data_array['instruction_date'];
        }

        $cases_data = TableRegistry::get('icases')->find('all')
                ->select(['icases.id', 'icases.state', 'icases.client_id', 'icases.name', 'icases.age', 'icases.case_reference_i_d', 'icases.go_date', 'clients.name'])
                ->innerJoin('icases_users', 'icases_users.icase_id = icases.id')
                ->where($conditions)
                ->innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id = icases.client_id')
                ->order(['clients.name' => 'ASC', 'icases.name' => 'ASC'])
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Now there is a state column in icases table and I want to filter by

```
icases.state='active' OR icases.state='pending' OR icases.state='archive'
```

My question is how do I integrate it into my existing $conditions array?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$conditions['status IN'] = ['active', 'pending', 'archive'];`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the [Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) provided by cake. The first example suits your need as far as I understand.

So you should add this before executing the query

```
$conditions['OR'] = [['icases.state' => 'active'], ['icases.state' => 'pending'], ['icases.state' => 'archive']];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is an solution to find all matching with `OR` conditions

```
$conditions = [];     #For storing all of your conditions as an array

if($filter_data_array['age_younger'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.age <= "] = $filter_data_array['age_younger'];
}

if($filter_data_array['age_older'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.age >= "] = $filter_data_array['age_older'];
 }

if($filter_data_array['go_date_after'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.go_date >= "] = $filter_data_array['go_date_after'];
}

if($filter_data_array['go_date_before'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.go_date <= "] = $filter_data_array['go_date_before'];
}

if($filter_data_array['client'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.client_id = "] = $filter_data_array['client'];
}

if($filter_data_array['case_name'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.name = "] = $filter_data_array['case_name'];
}

if($filter_data_array['case_ref'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.case_reference_i_d = "] = $filter_data_array['case_ref'];
}

if($filter_data_array['instruction_date'] != ''){
    $conditions[]["icases.date_instruction_received >= "] = $filter_data_array['instruction_date'];
}

$cases_data = TableRegistry::get('icases')->find('all')
        ->select(['icases.id', 'icases.state', 'icases.client_id', 'icases.name', 'icases.age', 'icases.case_reference_i_d', 'icases.go_date', 'clients.name'])
        ->innerJoin('icases_users', 'icases_users.icase_id = icases.id')
        ->where(['OR'=>$conditions])   #All of your `OR` conditions here
        ->innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id = icases.client_id')
        ->order(['clients.name' => 'ASC', 'icases.name' => 'ASC'])
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

**Note :** Your code has been changed like as -

```
$conditions[INDEX] to $conditions[][INDEX]
```

AND

```
->where($conditions) to ->where(['OR'=>$conditions])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend to follow the [CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html). Your Code would become much more readable.

I would also recommend to [connect your relations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) inside the Table objects. This keeps your code DRY and you can just load the associated models by using `contain` instead of 'manually' using `innerJoin`.

Check out the following code. It’s not tested, but should work. Using the [Advanced conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) is a little more 'Cake-ish' and easily mantainable. If you don’t care about the rest, just have a look at the `$orConditions` in the code.

```php
$query = TableRegistry::get('Cases')->find('all')
    ->select([
        'Cases.id', 
        'Cases.state', 
        'Cases.client_id', 
        'Cases.name', 
        'Cases.age', 
        'Cases.case_reference_i_d', 
        'Cases.go_date', 
        'Clients.name'
    ])
    ->order([
        'Clients.name' => 'asc', 
        'Cases.name' => 'asc'
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Clients',
        'Users'
    ])
    ->where(function ($exp) use ($filter_data_array) {

        if (!empty($filter_data_array['age_younger'])) {
            $exp = $exp->lte('Cases.age', $filter_data_array['age_younger']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['age_older'])) {
            $exp = $exp->gte('Cases.age', $filter_data_array['age_older']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['go_date_after'])) {
            $exp = $exp->gte('Cases.go_date', $filter_data_array['go_date_after']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['go_date_before'])) {
            $exp = $exp->lte('Cases.go_date', $filter_data_array['go_date_before']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['client'])) {
            $exp = $exp->eq('Cases.client_id', $filter_data_array['client']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['case_name'])) {
            $exp = $exp->eq('Cases.name', $filter_data_array['case_name']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['case_ref'])) {
            $exp = $exp->eq('Cases.case_reference_i_d', $filter_data_array['case_ref']);
        }
        if (!empty($filter_data_array['instruction_date'])) {
            $exp = $exp->gte('Cases.date_instruction_received', $filter_data_array['instruction_date']);
        }

        $orConditions = $exp->or_([
            'Cases.state' => 'active',
            'Cases.state' => 'pending',
            'Cases.state' => 'archive'
        ]);

        return $exp->add($orConditions);
    });

$cases_data = $query->execute();
```